# vim + solarized colorscheme + lxterminal

Tags: vim, background, color-scheme, xterm

I'm trying to install Solarized colorschem for vim, unfortunately i have some background problem: [screen & ~/.vimrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NubX5.png)

i do all necessary `~/.vimrc` settings:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set t_Co=256 
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

in vim `:echo $TERM` return `xterm-256color`
and `:set t_Co?` return `t_Co=256`

Also, i check my terminal(lxterminal) for 256color support by Colortest utility from vim.org and i got [this rgb grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOOYR.png).

I don't find solution of my problem and have no idea what else i'm supposed to do, that's why i start new topic

Comment: I cannot see what problem do you have....

Comment: on the screenshot vim background not the same as in solarized colorscheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to config your terminal with solarized theme too.

check http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized, and search keyword: `please please please`you are gonna see:

> IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS:
>
> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI
>   version like gvim or macvim), **please please please** consider setting
>   your terminal emulator’s colorscheme to used the Solarized palette.....